# Why doesn't converting the dtype of a Tensor fix "RuntimeError: expected scalar type Double but found Float"?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

The important part of my code looks like this:

```
def forward(self, x):
        x = T.tensor(x).to(self.device)
        x = x.type(T.DoubleTensor)
        x = self.conv1(x)
        ...
```

Yet I still get the error `expected scalar type Double but found Float` on the last line of that snippet. The line `x = x.type(T.DoubleTensor)` should fix that, right? I've also tried `x = x.double()` and  `x = T.tensor(x, dtype = T.double).to(self.device)` for the earlier line, and I still get the error. I'm at a loss, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyTorch expects the input to a layer to have the same device and data type (dtype) as the parameters of the layer. For most layers, including conv layers, the default data type is `torch.float32`, i.e. a `FloatTensor`.

To fix your issue you can cast `x` to be the same type as the `weight` or `bias` parameters of the `self.conv1` layer (assuming this is a `nn.Conv*d` layer).

```py
def forward(self, x):
    x = T.tensor(x, device=self.device, dtype=self.conv1.weight.dtype)
    x = self.conv1(x)
    ...
```

Most likely `self.conv1.weight.dtype` will just be `torch.float32`. Unless you've explicitly changed your model parameter types using something like `model.to(dtype=torch.float64)` then you could equivalently just use

```py
def forward(self, x):
    x = T.tensor(x, device=self.device, dtype=torch.float32)
    x = self.conv1(x)
    ...
```

Comment: Right, ok. I was really thrown off becuase the error seemed to suggest that the dtype expected was Double, which I thought I had set it to. But, of course, you were right, it was float32, though I though that was double, but in any case, setting it to float32 fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading. You should convert the original data's dtype to `float32` rather than `double`.

How I fixed it:

```
data_X = np.array(data.iloc[:, 2:7], dtype='float32')
data_y = np.array(data['output'], dtype='float32')
```